# Algorithm for plotting polar equations in general form

Tags: algorithm, math, plot, graphics, polar-coordinates

I'm looking for an algorithm, which can decide if a given point (x,y) satisfies some equation written in polar form, like r-phi=0. The main problem is that the angle phi is bounded between (0,2pi), so in this example I'm only getting one cycle of the spiral. So how can I get all the possible solutions for any polar equation written in such form?

Tried bounding r value to (0-2pi) range, which didn't work on some more complicated examples like logarithmic spirals

Comment: I doubt it will be possible to do reliably because of accuracy.

Comment: Welp, i don't actually think that accuracy is the problem, because I have no problem plotting equations in general form just by checking all the points on the screen. That's what I also want to do in polar form

Comment: Just because a point and a line you are plotting both want to color the same pixel doesn't mean the point is on the line. Stupid example: a screen with 1 pixel.

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous: the title is about plotting, and the body talks about checking a solution and about finding all solutions !?!

Comment: Just bad wording on my side. All i want to do is to check if a point (x,y) is a solution for some f(r,phi)=0, for example: f(r, phi) = sin(r^phi-phi/(r^2-r*phi)) where r and phi can be any real number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following transformation equations:

```
r = √(x² + y²)
φ = arctan(y, x) + 2kπ
```

where the function `arctan` is on four quadrants.

In the case of your Archimedean spiral, check that

```
(√(x² + y²) - arctan(y, x)) / 2π
```

is an integer.

Comment: This is the math, but when it comes to implementing it, it is a completely different story. Double or any precision just won't cut it. The program would really have to understand the symbols and mathematical functions and not just approximate them.

Comment: @maraca: don't be so blindly negative. If the equations allow it, symbolic computation is possible. And if not, correct tolerancing will do.

Comment: Symbolic calculation will work yes, that's what I'm saying. But I'm sure I can find functions where it fails also with "correct tolerancing". That's not blindly negative, that's cautious and considering all edge cases, a trait every programmer should have.

Comment: 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 (for doubles) do I need to say more? Also exponentiation will further increase the inaccuracy. Or add a huge number and subtract it again later, so you basically lost all accuracy. Something like r(phi) = (phi + eps) / pi, find all integer points only calculating with doubles...

Comment: It is a real example, it doesn't has to be eps, just a small number. Also stuff like r(phi) = x - y/phi that is basically becoming a circle with radius x but never reach it. There is an infinite amount of examples.

Comment: Well I think it should be at least mentioned on a programming website. You call them degenerated cases, that's just because those are the easiest examples to construct. Your answer implies to me that it is way easier than it actually is. What the 0.1 + 0.2 example already shows.

Comment: @maraca: you must be illiterate in numerical methods, or bad faith.

Comment: Great move! Attacking me and deleting your refuted points. My goal was never to attack you, I just think that piece of information is essential here, so I added a comment. Otherwise there will be people blindly implementing it and don't understand why it sometimes doesn't work. I'm sure you know the catastrophes happening because of rounding errors. So it's almost irresponsible to not even mention that problem.